# Show that $f = 0$ if $\int_a^b f(x)e^{kx}dx=0$ for all $k$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The problem is show that $f=0$ whenever $f\in C[a,b]$ and
$$\int_a^bf(x)e^{kx}dx =0, \hspace{1cm}\forall k\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, letting $u=e^x$ we note that $\int_{e^a}^{e^b}f(\ln u)u^{k-1}du=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

Next, see the following old questions:

[Nonzero $f \in C([0, 1])$ for which $\int_0^1 f(x)x^n dx = 0$ for all $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/nonzero-f-in-c0-1-for-which-int-01-fxxn-dx-0-for-all-n?lq=1)

[If $f$ is continuous on $[a , b]$ and $\int_a^b f(x) p(x)dx = 0$ then $f = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116086/if-f-is-continuous-on-a-b-and-int-ab-fx-pxdx-0-then-f-0)

[problem on definite integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222731/problem-on-definite-integral)

Comment: Very good @JonasMeyer. But, note that, $f(\log u)$ is approximated by $p(\log u)$ and not by $p(u)$!

Comment: @KelsonVieira: That is not what I had in mind, else I could have invoked Stone-Weierstrass as julien did.  The function $g:[e^a, e^b]\to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(u)=f(\ln u)$ is continuous, hence uniformly approximable by polynomial functions on $[e^a,e^b]$.

Comment: Really @Jonas. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can change variables and turn this into an application of the Weierstrass Theorem (density of the real polynomials in $C([e^a,e^b],\mathbb{R})$. That's Jonas' answer.

Or you can use the real version of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

The subalgebra $\{a_o+a_1e^x+\ldots+a_ne^{nx}\;|\;\in\mathbb{N},a_j\in\mathbb{R}\}$ of $C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ contains a non-zero constant function and separates points.
So it is dense in $C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$.

Take $g_n$ a sequence in this subalgebra that converges unformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$.
Then
$$
0=\int_a^bfg_n\longrightarrow \int_a^b f^2.
$$

Now if $f$ is continuous and $\int_a^bf^2=0$, we find that $f^2=0$, hence $f=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Julien!

Comment: You're most welcome.